# Setup of common objects when trial starts that are maintained across all tests

Tags: twisted, trial

Currently writing twisted trial tests for an multi-component order flow system that are run together in a single package.

Each test involves calls to external OS proxy objects that are used to regulate traffic - these are common across all tests being run in a package, but across different environments and executions, different ports/ip addresses may be assigned.

Using the test setUp and tearDown methods work, but require constant setting up of connections/port assignments for each test with uncertain wait times for ports to clear.

Is there a way to set up these objects when trial starts up before running the first test, maintain these objects and allow inspection of those object variables, and then allow a teardown on completion of the trial package containing the tests?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to do the set up when trial starts up; rather, you need to do the set up when trial runs the first test that depends on the given fixture.  Since trial runs a global reactor, you can use that for your final tear-down before Trial is done.

[There's an example of this in the way Calendar Server sets up a Postgres database for testing.](http://trac.calendarserver.org/browser/CalendarServer/trunk/txdav/common/datastore/test/util.py#L132)

Answer (score 0):

Use [testresources](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/testresources/):

> testresources is attempting to extend unittest with a clean and simple api to provide test optimisation where expensive common resources are needed for test cases